# Is it possible to receive URL data without adding callbacks in the UIApplicationDelegate?

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, nsnotificationcenter

I'm writing a shared manager class.  It knows to start and stop some services by listening for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and similar.  It's also supposed to do is to handle a certain set of URLs.  At the moment, I'm getting it to do that by adding code to the UIApplicationDelegate in each of our apps like so:

```
#pragma mark - URL support

// Pre 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
    return [[SGBMyManager sharedManager] handleOpenURL:url];
}

// For 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
{
    return [[SGBMyManager sharedManager] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

That works, but it's not very DRY.  I'd like to only have to code this once, in my shared manager class.  Is there a `UIApplicationDidHandleOpenURL` notification or similar that I could listen for?